# add multiple shapes to jpanel with delay

Tags: jpanel, delay, shapes

I want to add squares onto a jpanel one at a time after a delay . My program works fine until I tried to change the background color with setBackgound(). It didn't change. I worked out I have to call super.paintComponent(gr) in my paintComponent method. But when I do this and call repaint(), only the current square is displayed.The previous one's have disappeared. I know it is because repaint is displaying a whole new panel each timebut why does it work when I don't call super.paintComponent(). Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Squares extends JFrame{
    aPanel ap = new aPanel();   
    SlowDown sd = new SlowDown(); //slows down program by given number of milliseconds 

    public Squares(){
        super("COLOURED SQUARES");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(ap);
        ap.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        addSquares();
   }

    private void addSquares(){
        sd.slowDown(500);
        ap.changeSquare( 100 , 100 , 255 , 0 , 0);
        ap.repaint();

        sd.slowDown(500);
        ap.changeSquare( 200 , 200 , 0 , 0 , 255);
        ap.repaint();     
   }



    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Squares sq  = new Squares();
    }


class aPanel extends JPanel{

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private int r = 0;
    private int g = 0;
    private int b = 0;  

    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
        //super.paintComponent(gr);
        Color theColor = new Color (r, g, b);
        gr.setColor(theColor);
        gr.fillRect(x,y,30,30); 
    }
    void changeSquare(int i , int j, int rd , int gr , int bl){
        x = i;
        y = j;
        r = rd;
        g = gr;
        b = bl;
    }
}

class SlowDown{
    void slowDown(long delay){
         long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
         long startTime = t;
         while(t < startTime + delay){
             t = System.currentTimeMillis();            
         }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there is a number of things you can do to improve the code. First, if you want to draw a number of rectangles and "remember" the rectangles then you would need to store the rectangles that was drawn in the past. Otherwise what happens is that you basically paint over the previously drawn rectangle each time. So I would suggest storing each rectangle in a List of some sort. Then on paint you can loop throughthe list and draw each rectangle.

Secondly, the delay can be done with a Thread.sleep() call. Maybe this will be an example:

```
class APanel extends JPanel{

  List<Shape> rects;  
  private int r = 0;
  private int g = 0;
  private int b = 0; 

  public APanel(){
         rects = new ArrayList<Shape>();
  }

public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Color theColor = new Color (r, g, b);
    gr.setColor(theColor);
    for(Shape s: rects){
       ((Graphics2D)gr).fill(s);
    }        
}

void changeSquare(int i , int j, int rd , int gr , int bl){
    rects.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(i, j, 30, 30));        
    //we have to deal with colors
}
}
```

Now, the above example will allow you to continually add new rectangles to the list and each time paint all the rectangles. If you need to paint each rectangle in a different color then you may have to create your own rectangle class to store in the List. As for the delay you can do this:

```
 class SlowDown{
    void slowDown(long delay){          
       Thread.sleep(delay);
  }
 }
```

And that should pause things for delay milliseconds.

Comment: I was curious as to why the original code works if I dont use super.paintComponent(gr). Except for not being able to change background color it does what I want without setting up ArrayList's

Comment: Its not that the original code was wrong. But it was a limited way to approach the problem. Especially that you have the requirement to change the background and leave the squares on the screen. That is why I suggest the ArrayList of Rectangle Shapes.

Comment: OK but it doesn't answer my question as to why it works if I don't call super.paintComponent(gr). thanks

Comment: When you call super.paintComponent you are basically painting the entire component in its background colour over painting anything that was previously drawn including all the past squares. When you do not make the call the things you draw in th epast remain.